# Button on first fragment moves out of screen when replaced with second fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to use multiple `Fragment`s on an `Activity`. What I am doing is:
1. Add the first `Fragment` to the `Activity`. The first `Fragment` contains a button at the bottom of the screen.
2. Replace it with the second `Fragment` by adding it to the backstack.

When I click on the button on the bottom of the first `Fragment`, it automatically slides up (I don't know why) and moves to second `Fragment`:

[image: img1]

When I go back to the first `Fragment` by pressing the back button, the button in the first `Fragment` goes out of view:

[image: img2]

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UserDetailsFragment.UserDetailsFragmentListener,
        PhotoFragment.PhotoFragmentListener, TestFragment.TestFragmentListener{

@Bind(R.id.container)
FrameLayout frameLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_profile);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);


    // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
    // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
    // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        return;
    }

    initView();
}

private void initView() {

    TestFragment testFragment = new TestFragment();

    FragmentUtil.replaceFragment(this,R.id.container, testFragment);
}

@Override
public void onProfileDetailCompleted(UserModel userModel) {
    PhotoFragment photoFragment = PhotoFragment.newInstance(userModel);
    FragmentUtil.replaceFragment(this, R.id.container, photoFragment);
}

@Override
public void onPhotoUploaded(UserModel userModel) {

}

@Override
public void onSkipPhotoClicked() {
    PhotoFragment photoFragment = PhotoFragment.newInstance(null);
    FragmentUtil.replaceFragment(this, R.id.container, photoFragment);
}

@Override
public void onTest() {
    PhotoFragment photoFragment = PhotoFragment.newInstance(null);
    FragmentUtil.replaceFragment(this, R.id.container, photoFragment);
}
```

}

**TestFragment.java**

```
public class TestFragment extends BaseFragment {


public TestFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public interface TestFragmentListener {
    void onTest();
}

private TestFragmentListener mListener;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}

@OnClick(R.id.next_btn)
public void onNextButtonClicked() {
    //TODO validate view


    if(mListener!=null)
        mListener.onTest();
}



@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof TestFragmentListener) {
        mListener = (TestFragmentListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement TestFragmentListener");
    }
}
```

}

**FragmentUtils.java**

```
public class FragmentUtil {

public static boolean hadFragment(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    return activity.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0;
}

public static void replaceFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, int contentId, BaseFragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    if (hadFragment(activity)) {
        transaction.replace(contentId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    } else {
        transaction.add(contentId, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}

public static void removeFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, BaseFragment fragment) {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .remove(fragment)
        .commit();
}


public static void showFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, BaseFragment fragment) {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .show(fragment)
        .commit();
}

public static void hideFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, BaseFragment fragment) {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .hide(fragment)
        .commit();
}

public static void attachFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, BaseFragment fragment) {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .attach(fragment)
        .commit();
}

public static void detachFragment(AppCompatActivity activity, BaseFragment fragment) {
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .detach(fragment)
        .commit();
}
```

}

If I move from the second `Fragment` to the third `Fragment` (which is the same as the first), the button on the bottom of the second screen will look fine. But the button on first `Fragment` still goes out of the view. The problem only exists in the view of the first `Fragment`. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

i had somewhat similar issue. I was using the appcompact theme and my bottom layout was going out of the screen when i replace fragment. Then I tried different theme after that it worked perfectly fine. So if your are also using app compact theme then try any other theme. Hope so it will solve your problem.